# widestring compatibility problem in Delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, delphi-2006, widestring

In a dll build with Delphi 2006

```
Foo(aPath: widestring);
begin
  _rootPath := aPath;
end;
```

In an executable built with Delphi 2010

```
_Foo := GetProcAddress(FooModule,’Foo’);
_Foo(‘123456’);
```

Stepping into the dll, aPath = '123'.  In fact any string I pass gets cut exactly in half.

1.) Why is my literal being halved?
2.) How do I fix it?

Comment: How is _Foo declared in D2010?

Comment: Please copy and paste **real code** from your Delphi editor. What you've posted is not valid Delphi code, and so I'm skeptical about how accurately you've represented your problem here. Include function and variable declarations.

Comment: @ Mason Wheeler - Incorrectly apparently.  I had _Foo = procedure (aPath: string).  Thanks.

Comment: Voted to close: No longer relevant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure the _Foo parameter is a widestring in 2010

Answer (score 2):

WideStrings reside in Windows heap and are not managed by Delphi memory manager. So WideStrings (unlike other long string types) can be shared between exe and dll without problems.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you get wrong data because WideString is a managed type and the memory manager for the dll and the executable are different.
If you can recompile the dll make aPath type to be PWideChar